# PhpExcel new line in cell

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpoffice

What I do:

1. query data from db
2. explode data and insert \n
3. prepare array
4. open tamplate
5. insert array into tamplate
6. try to replace \n with new line

How can I found \n and insert new line? For example I have in A1 next text "One\nTwo". I read text from A1

```
$ltr='A1';
$vle=$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell($ltr);
```

After this I try to insert text in A1 again in A1 and replace \n with new line in one cell

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell($ltr)->setValue("${vle}");
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($ltr)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

But it does not work for my.

For example:
[image]

So, if I open tamplate with text I can't replace \n in cells. What can I do?

**Upd.** I try use char(10) and insert formula (for example) `="hello"&char(10)&"world"` But inserted only `="hello"&char(10)`

Comment: How are you replacing `\n` in the text? There are examples showing multi-line cells in the Examples provided

Comment: @MarkBaker Issue has been resolved. I published the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I explode/implode str and insert \n I use ''. Need use ""

```
implode("\n", $array);
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're asking about [this issue on the PHPspreadsheet github issues log](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/156) then this is a problem with your understanding of PHP strings.

```
$dataArray = [
    ['2010', 'Q1', 'United\nStates', 790],
    ['2010', 'Q2', 'United States', 730],
    ['2010', 'Q3', 'United States', 860]
]
```

A `'\n'` in single quotes is treated as a literal `\n`; a `"\n"` in double quotes is treated as a new line character.  So either build your array using double quotes:

```
$dataArray = [
    ['2010', 'Q1', "United\nStates", 790],
    ['2010', 'Q2', "United States", 730],
    ['2010', 'Q3', "United States", 860]
]
```

or convert the literal `\n` to a new line using str_replace:

```
$modified = str_replace('\n', "\n", $original);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "char(10)" in excel formula. & = concantinate, and char(10) = \n

```
$textWithNewLine = '="hello"&char(10)&"world"';
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell($ltr)->setValue($textWithNewLine);
```

Comment: I see. use char(10) this is equivalent as new line in excel. 
$textWithNewLine = 'hello&char(10)&world'
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell($ltr)->setValue($textWithNewLine);

Comment: inserted only before first &. In your example inserted only ="hello"&char(10)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `MoodleExcelWorkbook` class in your Moodle Excel App and you want to set auto line wrap/break in the cell, use the code like this:

```
require_once $CFG->libdir . '/excellib.class.php';
$workbook = new \MoodleExcelWorkbook("-");
$workbook->send('YOUR_FILE_NAME.xlsx');
$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('YOUR_SHEET_NAME');
/* do your some stuff here */
/* make 'text_wrap' => true in $format attribute */
$worksheet->write_string(1/*row*/, 1/*col*/, 'YOUR_VALUE', ['text_wrap' => true]);
$workbook->close();
```